# Is it possible to create a loop for some functions but stop them when external information comes in?

Tags: arduino, bluetooth, rgb, arduino-ide, arduino-nano

I am new to this platform and to Arduino. I tried to create a bluetooth controller for RGB Leds using an arduino nano. My code works well but I'd like to make it "perfect" (if you understand what i mean). 
So, I designed an Android app on MIT-App-Inventor, and it allows me to click on a button and select an rgb effect that I want (static colors, rainbow effect and so on).
The problem is that when I have the "*looping*" effects, rainbow and mixed colors, they stop at one point and the colors freeze on the Led Strip.
I tried to create another variable that changes according to the type of effect selected, `int var = 1;` line 48. But by doing that, I cannot escape the loop anymore.
Any Ideas ?
PS : I am using WS2812b 3 meters Led Strip, an Arduino Nano and a HC-05 Bluetooth Module 
Here is the entire code :

```cpp
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
#include <Adafruit_NeoPixel.h>
#ifdef __AVR__
  #include <avr/power.h>
#endif

SoftwareSerial BT(10, 11);  // TX, RX of the Bluetooth Module 

#define PIXEL_PIN      5    // Data Pin of Led strip 
#define PIXEL_COUNT    160   // Number of LEDs in the strip
#define BRIGHTNESS   125   // use 96 for medium brightness
#define SPEED          5   // Speed of each Color Transition (in ms)
#define RAINBOW_SPEED  27    // Rainbow Transition speed



Adafruit_NeoPixel strip = Adafruit_NeoPixel(PIXEL_COUNT, PIXEL_PIN, NEO_GRB + NEO_KHZ800);

bool offOld = LOW;
bool WhiteOld = LOW;
bool RedOld = LOW;
bool GreenOld = LOW;
bool BlueOld = LOW;
bool YellowOld = LOW;
bool OrangeOld = LOW;
bool pinkOld = LOW;
bool purpleOld = LOW;
bool cyanOld = LOW;
bool RainbowOld = LOW;
bool rgbOld = LOW;
bool RandomOld = LOW;
int  showType = 0;


void setup() {

   BT.begin(9600);
   
   BT.println("Connected to Arduino");
   

  strip.setBrightness(BRIGHTNESS);  
  strip.begin();
  strip.show();

}

int var = 1;
char a;

void loop() {
  bool off = LOW;
  bool White = LOW;
  bool Blue = LOW;
  bool Red = LOW;
  bool Green = LOW;
  bool Yellow = LOW;
  bool Orange = LOW;
  bool pink = LOW;
  bool purple = LOW;
  bool cyan = LOW;
  bool Rainbow = LOW;
  bool rgb = LOW;
  bool Random = LOW;
  bool ende;
  
   if (BT.available())
   {
    a= (char)BT.read();



    if(a=='f')
    {
      off = HIGH;
      var = 1;
      BT.println("LEDs OFF");
    }else{
          off = LOW;
    }
    
// ===========================================================================================

    if(a=='w')
    {
      White = HIGH;
      var = 1;
      BT.println("LEDs turning White");
    }else{
          White = LOW;
    }
    
// ===========================================================================================

    if(a=='b')
    {
      Blue = HIGH;
      var = 1;
      BT.println("LEDs turning Blue");          
    }else{
          Blue = LOW;  
    }

// ===========================================================================================

if(a=='r')
    {
      Red = HIGH;
      var = 1;
      BT.println("LEDs turning Red");      
    }else{
          Red = LOW;  
    }

// ===========================================================================================

if(a=='g')
    {
      Green = HIGH;
      var = 1;      
      BT.println("LEDs turning Green");    
    }else{
          Green = LOW;
    }

// ===========================================================================================

if(a=='y')
    {
      Yellow = HIGH;
      var = 1;      
      BT.println("LEDs turning Yellow");    
    }else{
          Yellow = LOW;
    }
    
// ===========================================================================================

if(a=='o')
    {
      Orange = HIGH;
      var = 1;      
      BT.println("LEDs turning Orange");    
    }else{
          Orange = LOW;
    }

// ===========================================================================================

if(a=='p')
    {
      pink = HIGH;
      var = 1;      
      BT.println("LEDs turning Pink");    
    }else{
          pink= LOW;  
    }


// ===========================================================================================

if(a=='v')
    {
      purple = HIGH;
      var = 1;      
      BT.println("LEDs turning Purple");    
    }else{
          purple = LOW;  
    }


// ===========================================================================================

if(a=='c')
    {
      cyan = HIGH;
      var = 1;      
      BT.println("LEDs turning Cyan");    
    }else{
          cyan = LOW;  
    }


// ===========================================================================================

    if(a=='a')
    {
      Rainbow = HIGH;
      var = 0;
      BT.println("LEDs making Rainbow");    
    }else{
          Rainbow = LOW;  
    }
    
// ===========================================================================================

     if(a=='m')
    {
      rgb = HIGH;
      var = 0;      
      BT.println("LEDs making Mixed Colors");    
    }else{
          rgb = LOW;  
    }


// ===========================================================================================

     if(a=='e')
    {
      Random = HIGH;
      var = 0;      
      BT.println("LEDs turning random colors");    
    }else{
          Random = LOW;  
    }
    
}

if (off == LOW && offOld == HIGH) {
    delay(20);
   
    
    if (off == LOW) {
       do {
       showType = 0  ;                            // Off animation Type 0
     
      startShow(showType);
      } while (a=0);
    }
  }

// ===========================================================================================

if (White == LOW && WhiteOld == HIGH) {
    delay(20);
   
    
    if (White == LOW) {
       do {
       showType = 1  ;                            // White animation Type 1
     
      startShow(showType);
      } while (a=0);
    }
  }

  
// ===========================================================================================  
  
  if (Red == LOW && RedOld == HIGH) {
    delay(20);
   
    
    if (Red == LOW) {
       do {
       showType = 2  ;                            // Red animation Type 2
     
      startShow(showType);
      } while (a=0);
    }
  }

// ===========================================================================================

if (Green == LOW && GreenOld == HIGH) {
    delay(20);
   
    
    if (Green == LOW) {
       do {
       showType = 3  ;                            // Green animation Type 3
     
      startShow(showType);
      } while (a=0);
    }
  }
  
// ===========================================================================================

if (Blue == LOW && BlueOld == HIGH) {
    delay(20);
   
    
    if (Blue == LOW) {
       do {
     
       showType = 4  ;                            // Blue animation Type 4
     
      startShow(showType);
      } while (a=0);
    }
  }
  
  // ===========================================================================================

if (Yellow == LOW && YellowOld == HIGH) {
    delay(20);
   
    
    if (Yellow == LOW) {
       do {
       showType = 5  ;                            // Yellow animation Type 5
     
      startShow(showType);
      } while (a=0);
    }
  }
  
// ===========================================================================================

if (Orange == LOW && OrangeOld == HIGH) {
    delay(20);
   
    
    if (Orange == LOW) {
       do {
       showType = 8  ;                            // Orange animation Type 8
     
      startShow(showType);
      } while (a=0);
    }
  }

// ===========================================================================================

if (pink == LOW && pinkOld == HIGH) {
    delay(20);
   
    
    if (pink == LOW) {
       do {
       showType = 9  ;                            // Pink animation Type 9
     
      startShow(showType);
      } while (a=0);
    }
  }
  
// ===========================================================================================

if (purple == LOW && purpleOld == HIGH) {
    delay(20);
   
    
    if (purple == LOW) {
       do {
       showType = 10  ;                            // Purple animation Type 10
       startShow(showType);
      } while (a=0);
    }
  }

// ===========================================================================================

if (cyan == LOW && cyanOld == HIGH) {
    delay(20);
   
    
    if (cyan == LOW) {
     do {
       showType = 11  ;                            // Cyan animation Type 11
       startShow(showType);
     } while (a=0);
    }
  }
  
// ===========================================================================================

      if (rgb == LOW && rgbOld == HIGH) {
    delay(20);

    if (rgb == LOW) {
      
       showType = 6;                            // Mix animation Type 6
       startShow(showType);
      
       
    }
  }
  
// ===========================================================================================


    if (Rainbow == LOW && RainbowOld == HIGH) {
    delay(20);

    if (Rainbow == LOW) {
       
       showType = 7;                            // Rainbow animation Type 7
       startShow(showType);
    
      
    }
  }

// ===========================================================================================


    if (Random == LOW && RandomOld == HIGH) {
    delay(20);

    if (Random == LOW) {
       
       showType = 12;                            // Random colors Type 12
       startShow(showType);
    }
  }

  
WhiteOld = White;
RedOld = Red;
BlueOld = Blue;
GreenOld = Green;
YellowOld = Yellow;
OrangeOld = Orange;
pinkOld = pink;
purpleOld = purple;
cyanOld = cyan;
offOld = off;
RainbowOld = Rainbow;
rgbOld = rgb;
RandomOld = Random;
}


void startShow(int i) {
  switch(i){

    case 0: colorWipe(strip.Color(0, 0, 0), SPEED);    // Black/off
            break;

    case 1: strip.setBrightness(255);                            // Changes the Brightness to MAX
            colorWipe(strip.Color(255, 255, 255), SPEED);  // White
            strip.setBrightness(BRIGHTNESS);                     // Reset the Brightness to Default value
            break;  

    case 2: colorWipe(strip.Color(255, 0, 0), SPEED);  // Red
            break;

    case 3: colorWipe(strip.Color(0, 255, 0), SPEED);  // Green
            break;

    case 4: colorWipe(strip.Color(0, 0, 255), SPEED);  // Blue
            break;

    case 5: colorWipe(strip.Color(255, 220, 0), SPEED);  // Yellow
            break;
    
    case 8: colorWipe(strip.Color(255, 100, 0), SPEED);  // Orange
            break;

    case 9: colorWipe(strip.Color(255, 0, 127), SPEED);  // pink
            break;

    case 10: colorWipe(strip.Color(127, 0, 255), SPEED);  // purple
             break;

    case 11: colorWipe(strip.Color(0, 255, 255), SPEED);  // cyan
             break;
            
    case 6: do {
              colorWipe(strip.Color(255, 220, 0), SPEED);  // Yellow
              colorWipe(strip.Color(255, 100, 0), SPEED);  // Orange
              colorWipe(strip.Color(255, 0, 0), SPEED);  // Red
              colorWipe(strip.Color(255, 0, 127), SPEED);  // pink
              colorWipe(strip.Color(127, 0, 255), SPEED);  // purple
              colorWipe(strip.Color(0, 0, 255), SPEED);  // Blue
              colorWipe(strip.Color(0, 255, 255), SPEED);  // cyan
              colorWipe(strip.Color(0, 255, 0), SPEED);  // Green
              theaterChase(strip.Color(255, 220, 0), SPEED);  // Yellow
              theaterChase(strip.Color(255, 100, 0), SPEED);  // Orange
              theaterChase(strip.Color(255, 0, 0), SPEED);  // Red
              theaterChase(strip.Color(255, 0, 127), SPEED);  // pink
              theaterChase(strip.Color(127, 0, 255), SPEED);  // purple
              theaterChase(strip.Color(0, 0, 255), SPEED);  // Blue
              theaterChase(strip.Color(0, 255, 255), SPEED);  // cyan
              theaterChase(strip.Color(0, 255, 0), SPEED);  // Green
            }while (var == 0);

    case 7: do {
              rainbowCycle(25);
            }while (var == 0);

    case 12: do {
              colorWipe(strip.Color(random(0, 255),random(0, 255),random(0, 255)), SPEED);
             }while (var == 0);
}
}

void colorWipe(uint32_t c, uint8_t wait) {
  for(uint16_t i=0; i<strip.numPixels(); i++) {
    strip.setPixelColor(i, c);
    strip.show();
    delay(wait);
  }
}

void rainbowCycle(uint8_t wait) {
  uint16_t i, j;

  for(j=0; j<256*2; j++) { // 5 cycles of all colors on wheel
    for(i=0; i< strip.numPixels(); i++) {
      strip.setPixelColor(i, Wheel(((i * 256 / strip.numPixels()) + j) & 255));
    }
    strip.show();
    delay(wait);
  }
}

void theaterChase(uint32_t c, uint8_t wait) {
  for (int j=0; j<10; j++) {  //do 10 cycles of chasing
    for (int q=0; q < 3; q++) {
      for (int i=0; i < strip.numPixels(); i=i+3) {
        strip.setPixelColor(i+q, c);    //turn every third pixel on
      }
      strip.show();

      delay(wait);

      for (int i=0; i < strip.numPixels(); i=i+3) {
        strip.setPixelColor(i+q, 0);        //turn every third pixel off
      }
    }
  }
}

uint32_t Wheel(byte WheelPos) {
  WheelPos = 255 - WheelPos;
  if(WheelPos < 85) {
    return strip.Color(255 - WheelPos * 3, 0, WheelPos * 3);
  }
  if(WheelPos < 170) {
    WheelPos -= 85;
    return strip.Color(0, WheelPos * 3, 255 - WheelPos * 3);
  }
  WheelPos -= 170;
  return strip.Color(WheelPos * 3, 255 - WheelPos * 3, 0);
}
```

Comment: You can maybe use [interrupts](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/external-interrupts/attachinterrupt/). You can call a function depending on input change WHATEVER is happening in the code, even if you are inside a loop, if the pin went from LOW to HIGH and you have attached interrupt on that pin on HIGH, it will pause the loop, call your custom function, and then continue.

Comment: Way, way too much code.  Make a minimum reproducible example.

Answer (score 0):

If you are the beginner, I suggest using `MsTimer2` library, which calls a function (a callback function) periodically based on the interrupt. So, you can periodically read and check the received character from the BT module in the callback function.
Just refer to the example here: https://playground.arduino.cc/Main/MsTimer2/

The example shows toggling a led every 0.5 seconds by periodically calling `flash()` function, even though the program runs in the infinite `loop()` function.

Edit) Fortunately, you don't need to understand what interrupt is when using `MsTimer2` thanks to its simplicity. But I recommend you to study about interrupt since it essential to using micro-controllers including Arduino families, like your case.